# EST with Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, ssl, cryptography, bouncycastle, pki

I try to request a new certificate via EST protocol from the EST test service URL “https://testrfc7030.com/”. The program uses Bouncy Castle for this.

I have already configured the EST service’s TA and my client certificate obtained from them. I also use the BC JSSE provider to get access to the “tls-unique” channel binding value.

```
        eSTService = new JsseESTServiceBuilder(Config.CredAdmin.caHost, trustManagers)
                    .withKeyManagers(keyManagers)
                    .withProvider(BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
                    .withChannelBindingProvider(new ChannelBindingProvider() {
                        //Use an anonymous binding provider that supports linking 
                        //Identity and POP Information (RFC7030, Section 3.5.), that
                        //relies on Channel Bindings for TLS (RFC5929) using "tls-unique".
                        public boolean canAccessChannelBinding(Socket sock) {
                            boolean ret = sock instanceof BCSSLSocket;
                            if (!ret)
                                //should never happen
                                MyUtils.LambdaLogger.error("Can't get channel binding value, check if BouncyCastleJsseProvider could be loaded.");
                            return ret;
                        }
                        public byte[] getChannelBinding(Socket sock, String binding) {
                            BCSSLConnection bcon = ((BCSSLSocket)sock).getConnection();
                            if (bcon == null) {
                                //should never happen
                                MyUtils.LambdaLogger.error("Can't get \"%s\" channel binding value, check if BouncyCastleJsseProvider could be loaded.", binding);
                                return null;
                            }
                            byte[] ret = bcon.getChannelBinding(binding);
                            MyUtils.LambdaLogger.debug("retrieved %d bytes \"%s\" channel binding value", ret.length, binding);
                            return ret;
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
```

and

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider());
```

When I configure EST service port 9443 – that requires my client cert but no TLS channel binding – I do get a new certificate:

[image]

However, when I configure port 443 – that also needs TLS channel binding – although I get 12 bytes of “tls-unique” from BC JSSE, these won’t get accepted by the EST service testrfc7030.com, so it gives me an HTTP 401 – Unauthorized:

[image]

My problem is, I don’t know, what’s wrong:

- my code
- the BC JSSE implementation of “tls-unique” (RFC 5929)
- the EST service’s implementation of “tls-unique” (RFC 5929)?

Does someone have an implementation that works with the EST service “testrfc7030.com:443” art has at least an idea, what's wrong?

---**Update 1**---
I'm creating the `ContentSigner` as following:

```
ContentSigner signer = 
        new JcaContentSignerBuilder(MyUtils.Crypto.sha256WithRSAEncryption)
        .setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
        .build(keyPair.getPrivate());
```

and the `csrBuilder`:

```
    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder csrBuilder =
        new PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
            new X500Name(subjectDN),
            SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded()));
    csrBuilder.addAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest, extGen.generate());
```

with

```
    ExtensionsGenerator extGen = new ExtensionsGenerator();
    ...
```

This we then use as following:

```
    EnrollmentResponse resp = eSTService.simpleEnrollPoP(false, cb.csrBuilder, cb.signer, null);
```

Comment: It's unlikely the tls-unique is the problem, since it's just a copy of the first Finished message, which would have to be correct for the handshake to work anyway. Can you check (show) how you are creating the ContentSigner for the (presumed) call to simpleEnrollPoP?

Comment: I added an update to the original post. Personally, I believe there is something wrong with the Base64 encoding of the `tls-unique' in https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/327e0370061dd2f5b70b52906f3c300f608cc30d/pkix/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/est/ESTService.java#L368

Comment: By my reading of http://testrfc7030.com, port 443 looks like it needs HTTP user authentication, while your example call to simpleEnrollPop does not specify any. JcaHttpAuthBuilder can be used to create a suitable auth object.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the question.

The result of our test of testrfc7030.com is:
Port 443 – requires HTTP user auth + identity POP linking (the first here was not so clear to me from their web page, thank to @PeterDettman for clearing)
Port 8443: requires HTTP user auth but no identity POP linking
Port 9443: requires user auth with client certificate (obtained via Port 8443 or Port 443) but no identity POP linking

identity POP linking = TLS channel binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the input by Peter we were able to fix this problem as following:

```
    //just for testrfc7030.com
    ESTAuth auth = new JcaHttpAuthBuilder(null, "estuser", "estpwd".toCharArray())
            .setNonceGenerator(new SecureRandom())
            .setProvider("BC")
            .build();
    
    EnrollmentResponse resp = eSTService.simpleEnrollPoP(false, cb.csrBuilder, cb.signer, auth);
```

It turned out, that testrfc3070 requires the following authentication schemes:

- Port 443: requires HTTP user auth + identity POP linking
- Port 8443: requires HTTP user auth but no identity POP linking
- Port 9443: requires user auth with client certificate (obtained via Port 8443 or Port 443) but no identity POP linking

identity POP linking = TLS channel binding